# Building armhf PERL packages in a docker image using the arm64 host's kernel image

Tags: docker, gcc, arm64, armhf

I'm trying to build the OCS Unix agent using the following git project : https://github.com/OCSInventory-NG/Packager-for-Unix on a gitlab CI/CD pipeline.

I have docker images with armhf packages but, when running, the docker image uses my Ubuntu Server 22.04 x64 ARM64 kernel. Which makes perl modules compilation aarch64 compliant.

I need for my project to have PERL packages compiled in the armv7l format and not in the aarch64 one.

Please find below some screenshots og what I get using docker versus what I get by compiling the agent directly on the Raspberry Pi

[image]

[image]

I searched for cross compiling options or configuration but did not find something pertinent.

I tried building the docker images on armv7 architecture but the kernel used stays the docker's host one

Thanks a lot for reading and for your help.

Regards,
Arnaud